# Unable to use ON CONFLICT

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to use ON CONFLICT but I'm getting the error "near "ON": syntax error"

Acording to other pages this is a fairly new thing and i should update my sqlite version but i can't find out how, my current sqlite version is 3.21.0

This is the code im trying to use:

```
cdb.execute("INSERT INTO httpproxies (proxy, first , last , timesalive , timesdead ) VALUES (?, ? , ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT(proxy) DO UPDATE SET last = ?,timesalive = timesalive + 1",
    (proxy,t1,t1,1,0,t1))
conndb.commit()
```

Can anyone explain me how to upgrade my sqlite version or an alternative code ? I already tried pip install --upgrade pysqlite3 but it didnt work out, it stayed the same version as before

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is only supported since SQLite3 version 3.24.0.  You haven't given any indication on what platform you're running, so I can't give you advice on the best way to update your SQLite3 version.  You can, though, use different SQL to achieve your aim.  Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate the principle:

```
execute("INSERT INTO httpproxies (proxy, ...)")
if conflict-error
  execute("UPDATE httpproxies SET ... WHERE proxy=?")
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I also realized I forgot to mention that, I need to get it working on my ubuntu 16.04 VPS. Hope you can help me with that, on windows I already got it working flawlessly.